# Crawling the pair of tags from html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python 3.6 and Pycharm 2016.2 as editor

I would like to crawl the pairs of contents inside of "th" : "td" tags if "td" tag has a child tag which is input tag with "checked = 'chedcked'". I tried regEx, find_all from BeautifulSoup and others, but still have error messages.

Please help.

This is web site address: http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=652691&tbl=cyber

Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

popup_inspection = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=652691&tbl=cyber"
res = urllib.request.urlopen(popup_inspection)
html = res.read()
soup_inspection = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

insp_trs = soup_inspection.find_all('tr')
for insp_tr in insp_trs:
    # print(insp_td.text)
    th = insp_tr.find('th')
    td = insp_tr.find('td')

    if td.find('input', checked=''):
        print(th, ":", td)
    else: pass
```

Comment: Please show the error message. If we do not know what is the error, we cannot help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to locate the `th` elements followed by a `td` sibling. Then, we can locate the `input` element with `type="radio"` and present `checked` attribute. If there is one, we can locate the `label` element coming right after the radio `input`.

Sample implementation:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=652691&tbl=cyber"
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'}

    page = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    for label in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "th" and tag.find_next_sibling('td')):
        value_cell = label.find_next_sibling('td')

        # if combobox cell
        selected_value = value_cell.find("input", type="radio", checked=True)
        if selected_value:
            value = selected_value.find_next("label").get_text()
            print(label.get_text(), value)
```

Currently prints:

```
10. 보증유형 자가보증
13. 사고/침수유무(단순수리제외) 무
12. 불법구조변경 없음
```

This, of course, can and should be further improved but I hope the techniques used in the snippet would help you to get to the final solution.

Comment: I deeply appreciated your comment. I tried with your code, but it keeps returning the contents from the first table excluding the rest of tables. I checked the rest of tables having the similar tag layout such as ("input", type="radio", checked=True), but the result can't return them. Do you know why it happened by any chance?

Comment: I even added this code at the start of the code (for insp_table in soup_inspection.find_all('table', class_=True):)

Comment: @신종원 looks like the `checked=True` does not work for other cases - the input elements there don't have the `checked` attribute..thanks.

Comment: It really has... every row with check-box in every table has checked="checked" if it is checked..

Comment: @신종원 yeah, but you see it in the browser which would change HTML. Try looking at the source code of the tables downloaded by requests..

Comment: What I don't really understand is there is the "checked" attribute when I check that page with the developer tool in Chrome browser, but there isn't the "checked" attribute when I see the result in crawler... Any advice.. for this case?

Comment: @신종원 yeah, cause browsers try to make the HTML well-formed, they would modify HTML according to standards, e.g. add `tbody`, `thead` and other special attributes. Plus, they can execute javascript. `requests` would only give you the initial HTML of the page, it is not a browser..

Comment: thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it. I will keep try.